# Attempting to solve rotated array query through rotating the query instead of the array

Tags: java, algorithm

input:

> ```
> 3 2 3 1 2 3 0 1 2
> ```

first three define the number of elements in array, number of rotations to array, and the number of query's that will be made on that array respectively.

second three are the numbers that the array consists of.

the final three are the query's made on the array where array[query] should be the output

this is my code:

>

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int numberElements = in.nextInt();
    int numberRotations = in.nextInt();
    int numberQuerys = in.nextInt();
    int[] a = new int[numberElements];
    for(int a_i=0; a_i < numberElements; a_i++){
        a[a_i] = in.nextInt();
    }
    for(int a0 = 0; a0 < numberQuerys; a0++){
        int indexQuery = in.nextInt();
        for(int rotateQuery = 1; rotateQuery < numberRotations; rotateQuery++){
            if(indexQuery == numberRotations){
                indexQuery = 0;
            }
            else{
                indexQuery++;
            }

        }
        System.out.print(a[indexQuery]);
        if(a0 != numberQuerys){
        System.out.print("\n");
        }

    }
}
```

Why am i having an issue with large inputs?

Comment: *"Why am i having an issue with large inputs?"* Is that supposed to be a description of your problem? "having an issue" is **not** a problem description. Explain your problem, e.g. show input, and actual and expected output. That way we might be able to help.

Comment: sorry Andreas. Im new to stack-overflow and the expected formatting of questions. The expected output for that query would be : 2
3
1

Answer (score 0):

You're having an issue because you're wrapping `indexQuery` back to zero when it reaches `numberRotations`, but you should be wrapping when it reaches `numberElements` (*after* incrementing), which is the size of your array. If not, you could end up reading from past the end of the array if `numberRotations` is greater than `numberElements`.

A separate issue is that you should start counting `rotateQuery` from 0 or else you will do one less rotation than you want to, because the loop runs as long it is *less than* `numberRotations` not less than or equal. You can verify by stepping through with a debugger, which I recommend you do.

A more efficient approach would just be to add `numberRotations` to your index and use the modulo operator to handle the wrapping, instead of a loop:

```
indexQuery = (indexQuery + numberRotations) % numberElements;
```

This assumes `numberRotations` is positive, so you should probably add input verification checks for that also.

Comment: So i took a little of everyone's advice and came up with this:

Comment: for(int a_i=0; a_i < numberElements; a_i++){
            a[a_i] = in.nextInt();
        }
        for(int a0 = 0; a0 < numberQuerys; a0++){
            int indexQuery = in.nextInt();
           
            indexQuery = (indexQuery - numberRotations + numberElements) % numberElements;
            
            System.out.print(a[indexQuery]);
            
            System.out.print("\n");
            
            
        }

Comment: It works except i get a run time error on one of the test cases.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -82
 at Solution.main(Solution.java:23)

Comment: I think the problem is im getting a negative indexQuery.

Comment: When you read in numRotations, you can do this: numRotations %= numElements; so you never rotate more than 1 full cycle. This means numRotations won't be so large that you end up with a negative index

Comment: Also it's not clear from your question which direction the rotation is supposed to be

Answer (score 0):

just as @samgak said, it seemed your algorithm exist flaw:
change your input and make it rotate one times, the input is:

```
3 1 3 1 2 3 0 1 2
```

and the output should be:

```
3 1 2
```

and your output

```
1 2 3
```

an alternative solution is replace for loop:

```
for(int rotateQuery = 1; rotateQuery < numberRotations; rotateQuery++){
        if(indexQuery == numberRotations){
            indexQuery = 0;
        }
        else{
            indexQuery++;
        }
    }
```

with

```
indexQuery = (indexQuery - numberRotations%numberElements+ numberElements) % numberElements;
```

because rotate query is opposite with rotate array element so we should **subtract** *numberRotations* rather than **add** it.